Sum Total in Recycler view
I have a recycler view with around 15 rows. Each row has some Edit Texts and One Text View at the end.
My objective is to calculate Sum of all text views or perform any other operation over it and display the result at top in a text view (Total) outside the recycler view which is not a part of this recycler view. Please note each edit text has a text watcher and displaying result at the end of each row in a text view (Result). I want to sum all these results outside the recycler view at top in a text view which is a simple text view. Also that I am using fragments and view binding in My App UI](https://i.sstatic.net/Qi6ey.jpg)my project for your reference. I am attaching the app screenshot here. I am so desperate to get out of here as I am badly stuck. Kindly help me with the exact code and its placement also. I shall post other information as well if someone genius accepts this challenge and help me with the solution.
This my Fragment Activity Java
package com.example.evan.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.evan.R;
import com.example.evan.databinding.FragmentImperial2Binding;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;


public class Imperial2Fragment extends Fragment  {

ArrayList<Imperial2Model> imperial2Models = new ArrayList<>();




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

FragmentImperial2Binding binding = FragmentImperial2Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.rv);
RecyclerImperial2Adapter adapter = new RecyclerImperial2Adapter(getContext(),imperial2Models);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
setImperial2Models();

    return binding.getRoot();

} private void setImperial2Models(){
    String[] N  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.e_1);
    String[] L1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.e_2);
    String[] L2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.e_3);
    String[] B1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.e_4);
    String[] B2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.e_5);
    String[] H1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.e_6);
    String[] H2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.e_7);
    String[] R1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.r_1);
    String[] X1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.x_1);
    String[] X2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.x_2);
    String[] X3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.x_3);
    String[] X4 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.x_4);


    for (int i=0;i<N.length; i++){
       imperial2Models.add(new Imperial2Model(N[i],L1[i],L2[i],B1[i],B2[i],H1[i],
               H2[i],X1[i],X2[i],X3[i],X4[i],R1[i]));
    }
}


}

This is my Adapter Class:
package com.example.evan.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.evan.R;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerImperial2Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerImperial2Adapter.MyViewHolder> {
Context context;
ArrayList<Imperial2Model> imperial2Models;
public RecyclerImperial2Adapter(Context context,ArrayList<Imperial2Model> imperial2Models) {
    this.context=context;
    this.imperial2Models=imperial2Models;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerImperial2Adapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_imperial_row,parent,false);

    return new RecyclerImperial2Adapter.MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerImperial2Adapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.n.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getN());
    holder.l1.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getL1());
    holder.l2.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getL2());
    holder.b1.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getB1());
    holder.b2.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getB2());
    holder.h1.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getH1());
    holder.h2.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getH2());
    holder.x1.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getX1());
    holder.x2.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getX2());
    holder.x3.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getX3());
    holder.x4.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getX4());
    holder.r.setText(imperial2Models.get(position).getR());



    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.n.getText().toString())){
                double a = TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.n.getText().toString()) ? 0 :              
                           Double.parseDouble(holder.n.getText().toString());
                holder.x1.setText(""+a);
            }else holder.x1.setText("");

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.l1.getText().toString()) ||
                    !TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.l2.getText().toString())
            ) {
                double a = TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.l1.getText().toString()) ? 0 :           
                           Double.parseDouble(holder.l1.getText().toString());
                double b = TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.l2.getText().toString()) ? 0 :   
                           Double.parseDouble(holder.l2.getText().toString());
                double k = (a + b/12);
                holder.x2.setText(""+k);
            }else holder.x2.setText("");

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.b1.getText().toString()) ||
                    !TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.b2.getText().toString())
            ) {
                double a = TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.b1.getText().toString()) ? 0 :  
                           Double.parseDouble(holder.b1.getText().toString());
                double b = TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.b2.getText().toString()) ? 0 : 
                           Double.parseDouble(holder.b2.getText().toString());
                double k = (a + b/12);
                holder.x3.setText(""+k);
            }else holder.x3.setText("");

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.h1.getText().toString()) ||
                    !TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.h2.getText().toString())
            ) {
                double a = TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.h1.getText().toString()) ? 0 : 
                           Double.parseDouble(holder.h1.getText().toString());
                double b = TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.h2.getText().toString()) ? 0 : 
                           Double.parseDouble(holder.h2.getText().toString());
                double k = (a + b/12);
                holder.x4.setText(""+k);
            }else holder.x4.setText("");


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.x1.getText().toString()) || 
               !TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.x2.getText().toString())
               || !TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.x3.getText().toString()) || 
                  !TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.x4.getText().toString())) {
                double v = TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.x1.getText().toString()) ? 1 : 
                           Double.parseDouble(holder.x1.getText().toString());
                double w = TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.x2.getText().toString()) ? 1 : 
                           Double.parseDouble(holder.x2.getText().toString());
                double x = TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.x3.getText().toString()) ? 1 : 
                           Double.parseDouble(holder.x3.getText().toString());
                double y = TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.x4.getText().toString()) ? 1 : 
                           Double.parseDouble(holder.x4.getText().toString());
                double z = v * w * x * y;
                holder.r.setText(String.format("%.2f", z));
            } else holder.r.setText("");



        }
    };holder.n.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
      holder.l1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
      holder.l2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
      holder.b1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
      holder.b2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
      holder.h1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
      holder.h2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imperial2Models.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    EditText n,l1,l2,b1,b2,h1,h2;
    TextView r,x1,x2,x3,x4;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        n=itemView.findViewById(R.id.n);
        l1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.l1);
        l2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.l2);
        b1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.b2);
        h1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.h1);
        h2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.h2);
        x1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.x1);
        x2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.x2);
        x3=itemView.findViewById(R.id.x3);
        x4=itemView.findViewById(R.id.x4);
        r=itemView.findViewById(R.id.r);


    }
}

}
`
